# Retrieve Variable from onBindViewHolder in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to retrieve the variable value in my main class so, I can load this value into my database. I am not sure how to retrieve onBindViewHolder value in MainClas. I am able to display the item in the activity.

Complete Code requested by user.

```
    class TestProjectMenuDetail() : AppCompatActivity() { 
            var itemName=""
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
                recyclerView_main.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                recyclerView_main.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)

                   supportActionBar?.title=navBarTitle
                fetchJSON()
            }

            //Retrieve value from OnBindViewHolder
            fun setVariable(ItemName:String)
            {
                itemName=ItemName

            }
        }
        private class MenuDetailListAdapter(val TestProjectMenudetails:Array<TestProjectMenuDetails>,context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<TestProjectDetailMenuViewHolder>()
        {
 private  val TestVar:TestMenuDetail= context as TestMenuDetail
            override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: TestProjectDetailMenuViewHolder, p1: Int) {
                val TestProjectmenudetail=TestProjectMenudetails.get(p1)
                p0?.customView?.itemname.text=TestProjectmenudetail.menu



     TestVar.setVariable(TestProjectmenudetail.menu)

            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return TestProjectMenudetails.size
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): TestProjectDetailMenuViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context)
                val customView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_TestProject_menu_detail,p0,false)
                return TestProjectDetailMenuViewHolder(customView)
            }

        }
         @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
         class TestProjectDetailMenuViewHolder(val customView: View, var Menus:TestProjectMenu?=null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView)
        {
            companion object {
                val DISHES_TITLE_NAME="ITEM_NAME"
                val intialcount:Int=0
            }

            init {
                customView.setOnClickListener {
                }
            }
            fun AddClick()
            {
                val intent=Intent(customView.context,TestProjectMenuList::class.java)
                customView.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MainClas` declare a variable to hold the value you want to pass from `onBindViewHolder` like `activityVar` and then create a method:

```
fun setVariable(myVariable: Int) {
    activityVar = myVariable
}
```

replace `Int` with the proper data type.

Change your adapter class's header like this:

```
private class TestDetailListAdapter(context: Context, val ItemTestdetails:Array<ItemTestDetails>)
```

so you need to pass to it first the context of your activity by passing `this` 
and inside `onBindViewHolder` add this:

```
val mainclas: MainClas = context as MainClas 
mainclas.setVariable(variablename)
```

replace `variablename` with the name of the variable you want to pass

Comment: Getting unresolved reference error on context and .setVariable

Comment: Take setVariable() outside onCreate()

Comment: Before `onCreate()` declare `var activityVar = ""`

Comment: Inside `setVariable()` write `activityVar = ItemName`

Comment: Thanks for your response but still I am getting error at context val TestVar:TestMenuDetail=context as TestMenuDetail

Comment: What is the error? Did you pass `this` in the instantiation of the adapter in your activity?

Comment: Remove all that line from onBindViewHolder and put this: `private val mainClass : TestMenuDetail= context as TestMenuDetail` under the adapter's header

Comment: I changed it to private class MenuDetailListAdapter(context: Context,val TestProjectMenudetails:Array<TestProjectMenuDetails>): RecyclerView.Adapter<TestProjectDetailMenuViewHolder>() but I am not sure about the instantiation of the adapter class.

Comment: Now under this header put `private val TestVar: TestMenuDetail= context as TestMenuDetail` and remove `val TestVar:TestProjectMenuDetail=context as TestProjectMenuDetail` from onBindViewHolder

Comment: Also where is the line in your activity where you set the adapter of the recyclerview?

Comment: I am pulling JSON array for recycler view so, I am getting error message in the adapter over there   val TestProjectmenu=gson.fromJson(body,Array<TestProjectMenuDetails>::class.java)
                println("Restaranut Menu Details :$TestProjectmenu")
                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter=MenuDetailListAdapter(TestProjectmenu)
                } //Error Required context but found Array<TestMenuDetails>

Comment: Did you solve the unresolved reference context issue?

Comment: Inside the MenuDetailListAdapter it resolved the issue but it still throwing error inside JSON call.

Comment: This is a separate issue. Post another question with all the relevant code in your activity including fetchJSON()

Comment: Sure Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976260/getting-classifier-context-does-not-have-companion-object-in-kotlin